# Model name "Query" doesn't work with rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails 3.0.3 and I have a model named Query. When I call "all" or "find" on Query from application (I was calling it from User model) it says

```
"NoMethodError (undefined method `all' for ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Query:Module):"
```

As I checked in rails there is module query in

```
ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Query`
```

In:

```
activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/query.rb:
```

But if I call it from console, it works fine.

Any help, information?

Thanks and regards,
Pravin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query is probably a reserved word. It isn't listed in the official list of  [reserved words](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords), but rails is finding a conflicting file. Just change the model name as a workaround.

Comment: Confirmed, I ran into the same issue with a model named "Query" in rails 3.0.0. Changing it to FooQuery worked for me, too.

Comment: Confirmed with Rails 3.2.13. Modules conflict with the name Query as well. I tried using a concern named `__::__::Query` and received an undefined method error for all inner methods.