# Funneling a user input back through and model to render again

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

I have a jquery date selector in my view that sends the `:start_date` and `:end_date` into my model which successfully creates an entry in my `queries` model which has attributes `start_date` and `end_date`.

In my controller I have a line in a mySQL query that takes string variables `query.start_date` and `query.end_date`. Those successfully pull from the model if I hand-define the start_date and end_date methods with individual dates.

In my controller, I also have `query = Query.new` to instantiate a class.

Finally, here is the code in my model, with my main page reloading on successful entry of a date range (which should then generate a graph with said date range):

```
class Query < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :created_at, :start_date, :end_date

  validates_presence_of :start_date, :end_date

  def start_date
    start_date = Query.last.start_date
  end

  def end_date
    end_date = Query.last.end_date
  end
```

Currently, I'm getting an error `undefined method`last' for ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Query:Module`

I'm a bit confused about how to grab that last entry and have my page reload to display those date values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Query.all.last.end_date` or `Query.find(:all).last.end_date`

**Edit**

> Query is probably a reserved word. It isn't listed in the official
> list of [reserved words](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords), but rails is finding a conflicting file. Just
> change the model name as a workaround.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/4331159/643500

Comment: I get 'undefined method `find` or `all` depending on which of your suggestions I try.'